# How do I assign a value to a variable with IJSObjectReference in Blazor WebAssembly for .NET 5?

Tags: blazor, webassembly, blazor-webassembly, .net-5

Calling a method on a IJSObjectReference in Blazor for .NET 5 is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0):

```
module.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("callFunction", parameter); // module.callFunction(parameter)
```

But how would you assign a value to a variable on the referenced object? I've tried the following two but none of them work:

```
module.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("logging", true); // module.logging = true
module.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("logging = true;"); // module.logging = true
```

This is the error message I get:

> Unhandled Exception:
> Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'logging = ' ('logging = ' was undefined).

I'm trying to do the equivalent that we do in Javascript which is connect to a signalR Hub:

```
let connection = $.hubConnection('www.myserver.com/hubby');
connection.logging = true;
connection.start();
```